# Should this be a link or a secondary button?

Tags: interaction-design, buttons, hyperlinks

This is a wireframe and in development but we've recently been posed the question, "Should Edit Address be a text link (shown below) or a secondary button under the Primary "Confirm address" button.

[image: Primary CTA and text link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I approach questions like this (a quick thought experiment):

**Imagine digital screens don't exist, and you have to design a paper form instead.**

In this case, page hierarchy would probably look like this:

- Title: Your billing address
- Sub-title: Is this your address? "18 Atlas House..."
- Yes / No

Now, since you already got their address (hence displaying it in a drop-down), you can assume that "**Yes**" is the most likely answer, however, "No" is a semantically equal option => has to be a secondary button.

A secondary button should be visually similar to primary, but more subtle. So I would make it of the same shape at least.